# Dart/Flutter : Avoid Method parsing in Map , when converting to JSON?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, hashmap, closures

In Dart / Flutter , when converting a map (which contains a Closure method) to json using jsonEncode , I getting following error :

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Closure: () => dynamic
```

The Map having :

```
orderedMap1["fooddelete"] = () => deleteItemFunction(
          singleitem["orderId"], singleitem["id"], singleitem["shopId"]);
```

If commented above line , then jsonEncode works , else throwing above error .

How to instruct the jsonEncode to skip the closures when parsing Map to Json ?

Comment: Why are you storing closures in the `Map`?  If you don't want `jsonEncode` to encode the entire `Map`, you will need to remove the unwanted elements first or create a copy with just the elements you do want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems highly questionable to store closures in the same `Map` that you want to encode to JSON, but if you must, you can encode a filtered copy of it instead:

```dart
var encoded = jsonEncode({
  for (var entry in orderedMap1.entries)
    if (entry.value is! Function) entry.key: entry.value,
});
```

I suppose you alternatively could use [`jsonEncode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html)'s `toEncodable` parameter to convert closures to something else, although I'm not sure what good that would do you since there's nothing the recipient could do with it.  The following will replace closures with `null`:

```dart
var encoded = jsonEncode(orderedMap, toEncodable: (value) {
  if (value is Function) {
    return null;
  }
  throw UnsupportedError('Cannot convert to JSON: $value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

option1: remove "fooddelete" key using `orderedMap1.remove("fooddelete")` and then parse it.

option2: put your Closure inside the double quotation. so you can save it as String.

Comment: option 2: ==> If I put as a string , then how I able to execute the function when needed ?

Comment: as you know for passing data around your application, you have to use classes. the class can have any property. you can set one of them to hold your function. and use it where ever you want. your class has also a toJson. and you can customize what properties should be included in generated JSON. and when you are using toJson, it means you want to pass data to a server or something. not somewhere else in your app. so the recap is if you want to execute the function then you are passing data in your app and you should use class not JSON.